# Android studio Unable to find method void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to compile a simple Android apk file using Android Studio 2020.3.1 on Windows 10 21H1 x64, the project isn't mine: https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon, I downloaded the code as a zip file and added it to Android Studio as a project.

I have tried to build it (I have modified the drop rate and drop weights of items but otherwise left the code alone so it's likely not my fault) but it doesn't build, at first it stuck at gradle build so I deleted '.gradle' and '.idea' folders and wrote this file to disk:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

%userprofile%.gradle\gradle.properties

And invalidated cache and restarted Android Studio.

Now it fails at downloading this library: `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile`

```
Unable to find method ''void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)''
'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

```
'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile.<init>(java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel)'
    at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.unzip(InstallerUtil.java:99)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:90)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:335)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:365)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installBuildTools(DefaultSdkLoader.java:318)
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:155)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkFullLoadingStrategy.init(SdkFullLoadingStrategy.kt:49)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkFullLoadingStrategy.getFileFromTarget(SdkFullLoadingStrategy.kt:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkFullLoadingStrategy.getAndroidJar(SdkFullLoadingStrategy.kt:66)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkLoadingStrategy.getAndroidJar(SdkLoadingStrategy.kt:30)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkComponentsBuildService$VersionedSdkLoader$sdkSetupCorrectly$1.call(SdkComponents.kt:167)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkComponentsBuildService$VersionedSdkLoader$sdkSetupCorrectly$1.call(SdkComponents.kt:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultProvider.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:84)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAndroidProject(ModelBuilder.java:310)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:236)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.buildAll(ModelBuilder.java:156)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuilderWithParameter.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:248)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$UserCodeAssigningBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:322)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$UserCodeAssigningBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:322)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.lambda$build$0(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:265)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:385)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:385)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:366)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$LockSingleProjectBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:265)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder$1.call(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.internal.DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry$BuildOperationWrappingBuilder.build(DefaultToolingModelBuilderRegistry.java:297)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getParameterizedModel(DefaultBuildController.java:162)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction$MyBuildController.getModel(ProjectImportAction.java:564)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.findParameterizedAndroidModel(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:236)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.access$findParameterizedAndroidModel(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:48)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker$populateAndroidModels$modules$1$1.invoke(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:116)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker$populateAndroidModels$modules$1$1.invoke(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SequentialSyncActionRunner.runAction(SyncActionRunner.kt:61)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.SequentialSyncActionRunner.runActions(SyncActionRunner.kt:57)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateAndroidModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:113)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProviderWorker.kt:65)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidExtraModelProvider.populateBuildModels(AndroidExtraModelProvider.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:246)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:160)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.apply(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:133)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.apply(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:111)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$0(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:91)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:154)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:103)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
```

I have tried to redownload and resync many times and it doesn't work.

How to fix it?

---

I have found this file:

org.apache.commons.compress_1.19.0.v20200106-2343.jar

Where do I put it so that gradle can find it?

Its hash is AC4608FA367C0247E451BB88EDEB4B9B58E7159088579BF536608182BA37FD43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried downloading Shattered Pixel Dungeon and building its Android module -- I got the same error, initially. I was able to resolve it by first installing the Android 32 Build Tools from the SDK Manager (I also installed 31, but that didn't seem to change much), then changing the root build.gradle of Shattered Pixel Dungeon:

```
        appAndroidCompileSDK = 32
        appAndroidTargetSDK = 32
```

I also changed the Android Gradle Plugin to 7.0.4, at the top of the same build.gradle file. Note that this version of AGP isn't new enough to avoid a warning when targeting Android 32, but it doesn't seem to harm the build.

Other people who have had this problem on the libGDX Discord have claimed that downgrading both the Android Gradle Plugin (to 4.1.1) and Gradle itself (to 6.7.1, in this case) worked for them. I am not sure if that approach will work very well for the current Shattered Pixel Dungeon release, because some of the Gradle files have comments mentioning extra code present specifically for Gradle 7.x.